# Setting creation date or properties on local storage file in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, storagefile

How do I go about setting the creation date, or if that isn't possible a custom file attribute on a file using Windows.Storage in WP8?  If there's no way to do it with Windows Storage, is there any other way to store metadata with the file?  I'm not looking to use Isolated Storage settings or a database or anything.

Answer (score 0):

you want to get the file creation time? if this, you can get file creation date with using this code:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile isof = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (var fileStream = isof.OpenFile("myfile.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        byte[] htmlContentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test string");
        fileStream.Write(htmlContentBytes, 0, htmlContentBytes.Length);
    }

    var creationTime = isof.GetCreationTime("myfile.txt");// get creation time/date
    var lastAccessTime = isof.GetLastAccessTime("myfile.txt"); // get last access time/date
    var lastWriteTime = isof.GetLastWriteTime("myfile.txt"); // get last Write time/date
}
```

Comment: I didn't say "get" I said "set".